# How to shoot ray in specific direction in UE4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, blueprint, topdown

I'm trying to draw a debug line of certain length starting at my pawn position and moving in direction of mouse click, but I keep getting really weird results. Sometimes it works, but mostly does not. Seems like it depends on my character's location.
blueprint: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSGyb.jpg
screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUP3I.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your ray trace starts at a (correct) world location, but it ends at a relative location, since you're multiplying the X and Y coordinates of a unit vector by 500 - this will result in a value between (-500, -500, 0) and (500, 500, 0)

Instead, you want to add your multiplied unit vector to your line start location, which will give you a world location.